# Python string lists: How does one retrieve the unique values from the comparison of two lists of strings?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 2 lists of strings of unequal length, not sorted, and I want to retrieve the values that are unique to the longer list. The real lists I work with contains several thousands of values. The values present in listA are always found in listB. All the values are only found once in a given list.

example :

listA = ['b0001', 'b0003', 'b0007', 'b0004']
listB = ['b0001', 'b0005', 'b0007', 'b0017', 'b0004', 'b0003', 'b0002', 'b0432']

Expected result :

listC =  'b0005', 'b0017', 'b0002', 'b0432']

I've tried to use the set function and intersection or the enumerate function but only end up getting errors...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

A more proper way to do that is using sets.

```
setA = set(listA)
setB = set(listB)
listC = list(setB - setA)
```

Here the minus symbol means the difference between sets B and A.

best regards

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension :

```
>>> listC = [item for item in listB if item not in listA]
>>> listC
['b0005', 'b0017', 'b0002', 'b0432']
```